# Azure Active Directory override claim value in OIDC id-token

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I'm looking for a way to ensure that the unique_name claim value is always the user email for a specific app in AAD which is accessed via SSO. I've noticed that for users which have an AAD account, the unique_name claim value is the email address, but for external users (invited to the directory) it is prefixed by "live.com#" (e.g. live.com#email@domain.com). The application uses the OIDC protocol. I've been trying different things from Microsoft docs:

1. Setting a different source for the unique_name claim
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-claims-customization
   (I'm not sure if this applies, given the app uses OIDC, not SAML)

(By the way, that documentation is a bit out of date because I found that the "User Attributes & Claims" section is now in SSO https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/248748/cant39-find-the-34user-attributes-amp-claims34-sec.html)

2. Building a claim-mapping policy
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping

None of these worked.

I know this would be trivial in AAD B2C with custom policies. Is it possible to override the unique_name claim with the email claim in AAD?

---

Update 07/01/2022

After further investigation I found that the unique_name claim is only supported in v1 tokens https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens, https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/62971 (the current version is v2) and it's transformed into "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" by the ADAL client. This customization I'm after is for a legacy .NET app which uses ADAL on the v1 AAD endpoint.
The only way I can think of how to achieve this is via a claim-mapping policy, however I haven't been able to do make it work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I've found an answer to my question and the conclusion is that it's not possible to override the unique_name claim, because it's a restricted claim. The closest I got was to map the mail claim to a custom claim (e.g. unique_name2). This is what I did:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping

1. I installed the Azure AD PowerShell Module public preview (I had to uninstall the AD Powershell module first because I already had a later version)
2. I followed the instructions on the document above to connect to AAD and view any existing claim mapping policies

> Connect-AzureAD -Confirm
>
> Get-AzureADPolicy

3. I followed the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/80295/claim-transformation-in-azure-id-token-upn-data-to.html to build a claim mapping policy, although I had to adapt it because it wasn't working. I ran the following commands:

3.1 I used the search command to search for my app (called "test").

> GET-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString Test

This outputs a table like the following:

> ObjectId            AppId                  DisplayName
>
> ---

3.2 I ran the following command to create a new mapping policy which maps the "mail" claim to the "unique_name2" claim. (When I tried mapping to "unique_name" it works, but the "unique_name" claim doesn't get overridden, because it's a restricted claim)

> $Policy=New-AzureADPolicy -Definition
> @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true",
> "ClaimsSchema":[{"Source":"user","ID":"mail"},{"Source":"transformation","ID":"DataJoin","TransformationId":"JoinTheData","JwtClaimType":"unique_name2"}],"ClaimsTransformations":[{"ID":"JoinTheData","TransformationMethod":"Join","InputClaims":[{"ClaimTypeReferenceId":"mail","TransformationClaimType":"string1"}],
> "InputParameters":
> [{"ID":"string2","Value":""},{"ID":"separator","Value":""}],"OutputClaims":[{"ClaimTypeReferenceId":"DataJoin","TransformationClaimType":"outputClaim"}]}]}}')
> -DisplayName "MapMailToUniqueName2" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"

3.3 I ran the following command to add the custom policy to my app service principal (copying the id from step 3.1). This means the policy will be applied only to that specific app.

> Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id {my app service principal id}
> -RefObjectId $Policy.Id

That's all. When I tested SSO on my app, I had an additional claim "unique_name2" which contains the value of the "mail" claim.
There probably is a more efficient way of creating the mapping policy in step 3.2 but the way described in the step 3 link wasn't working for me so I came up with a concatenation to a blank string.

It doesn't seem possible to override the unique_naim claim because it's a restricted claim. I later found that this is actually documented here https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/develop/reference-claims-mapping-policy-type.md. I wish I had found this earlier.